# Display Values In Crystal Report With Multiple Tables in sqL

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have 3 tables in sqL server and i want to display them in one report, sum the TOTAL of the same supplier and SUM all the sales.

tblSalesCash Columns:Supplier,Total 
tblSalesCheck Columns:Supplier,Total 
tblSalesTerms Columns:Supplier,Total 

tblSalesCash 
********************************
*     SUPPLIER     |  TOTAL  |
********************************
*Yassin Marketing  |       2000|
*Yassin Marketing  |       5000|
********************************

tblSalesCheck 
********************************
*     SUPPLIER     |  TOTAL  |
********************************
*Yassin Marketing  |       5000|
*Yassin Marketing  |       5000|
********************************

tblSalesTerms
********************************
*     SUPPLIER     |  TOTAL  |
********************************
*Yassin Marketing  |       2000|
*Yassin Marketing  |       8000|
********************************

And I want to display them in my Crystal Report like this:

Crystal Report 
*************************************************************************************************
*     SUPPLIER     | TOTAL CASH | TOTAL CHECK | TOTAL TERMS | GRAND TOTAL |
*************************************************************************************************
*Yassin Marketing  |                 7000|                  10000|                  10000|                   27000|
*************************************************************************************************

so far this is my code:

```
SELECT tblSalesCash.Supplier, SUM(DISTINCT tblSalesCash.Total) AS TotalCash,
       SUM(DISTINCT tblSalesCheck.Total) AS TotalCheck,
       SUM(DISTINCT tblSalesTerms.Total) AS TotalTerms
FROM tblSalesCash INNER JOIN
            tblSalesTerms ON tblSalesCash.Supplier = tblSalesTerms.Supplier INNER JOIN
            tblSalesCheck ON tblSalesTerms.Supplier = tblSalesCheck.Supplier
GROUP BY tblSalesCash.Supplier, tblSalesTerms.Supplier, tblSalesCheck.Supplier
```

I have tried many codes but it doesn't give what I want to display and the sum sometimes are less or multiplied to itself, and also if I input multiple Suppliers it does not display all suppliers.

Comment: have you tried linking tables instead of writing the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can the fields for each table in separate detail sections of a report then create a group for the Supplier to put the total for each amount field.